# How to allow multiple product selection in Magento widget configuration?

Tags: php, magento-1.6, magento

I am trying to implement embedded widget. Administrators will be able to configure this widget and embed it inside WYSIWYG editor. Two of the many configuration options are list of products that should show up on frontend and list of categories.

I want to allow this selection with "**adminhtml/catalog_product_widget_chooser**" and "**adminhtml/catalog_category_widget_chooser**". I tried to implement these widgets with sparse documentation available on the web but all I managed to accomplish is implementation for selecting one product or selecting one category. I need multiselect behavior.

As far as I can see no multiselection possibility is allowed by the current implementation. I checked code for both classes and grid.phtml template and it seams it is badly written and not extensible beyond current intention of use. For example this is how you would suppose to initialize helper block for a widget parameter to allow multiple select:

```
<helper_block>
    <type>adminhtml/catalog_product_widget_chooser</type>
        <data>
            <button translate="open">
                <open>Select Products...</open>
            </button>
            <use_massaction>1</use_massaction>
        </data>
</helper_block>
```

But product chooser is hard coded for use without mass actions with this part of the code:

```
public function prepareElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $uniqId = Mage::helper('core')->uniqHash($element->getId());
    $sourceUrl = $this->getUrl('*/catalog_product_widget/chooser', array(
        'uniq_id' => $uniqId,
        'use_massaction' => false,
    ));
    ...
```

And grid.phtml template that is supposed to have some kind of button to confirm multiple selection is just showing "Search" and "Reset filter" buttons. And there is no handling of adding another button. For example here is the default code responsible for printing button html:

```
public function getMainButtonsHtml()
{
    $html = '';
    if($this->getFilterVisibility()){
        $html.= $this->getResetFilterButtonHtml();
        $html.= $this->getSearchButtonHtml();
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Only these two buttons are going to be printed by default.

So I started my own implementation based on two implementations mentioned above and it is getting ugly and could end up as an unmaintainable mess of copy-pasta. And I work by principle that if things start to look ugly then I am doing something wrong.

So is there a straightforward way to implement multiple product and multiple category selection on widget configuration screen by using grid widget?

Answer (score 5):

I've found a quick way to get category multiselects on widget parameters using a source model based on `adminhtml/system_config_source_category`. I've removed the root-level filter and added indentation for subcategories.

widget.xml:

```
<widgets>
    <my_widget type="mymodule/block" translate="name" module="mymodule">
        <name>Widget with Multiselect Categories</name>
        <parameters>
            <category_ids translate="label description">
                <visible>1</visible>
                <required>1</required>
                <label>Categories</label>
                <type>multiselect</type>
                <source_model>mymodule/system_config_source_category</source_model>
            </category_ids>
        </parameters>
    </my_widget>
</widgets>
```

The source model:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_System_Config_Source_Category
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addFieldToFilter('path', array('neq' => '1'))
            ->load();

        $options = array();

        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $depth = count(explode('/', $category->getPath())) - 2;
            $indent = str_repeat('-', max($depth * 2, 0));
            $options[] = array(
               'label' => $indent . $category->getName(),
               'value' => $category->getId()
            );
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: Multiselect widget parameter]

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-2

Comment: Please specify: Should the source code be placed in file: `Mymodule/Model/System/Config/Source/Category.php`?

Answer (score 4):

I have added an answer to this question.
[Implement multiple product chooser widget Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389150/implement-multiple-product-chooser-widget-magento)

I have checked the Module that is under https://github.com/dio5/magento-multiproducts-widget.

Use the FORK option instead of Download ZIP.

It works and gives us the exact results i.e Multiple Products Selection in WIDGET. If there are any errors do let me know.

Let me know if that works for you.

Thanks!

[Editing my previous comment, upon request of code here directly]

> /Namespace/Modulename/etc/widget.xml

```
<widgets>
  <catalog_product_multiproducts type="namespace_modulename/widget_catalog_product_multiproducts" translate="name description" module="namespace_modulename">
    <name>Catalog Multiple Products Widget</name>
    <description>Select multiple products for display</description>
    <parameters>
        <title translate="label">
            <visible>1</visible>
            <label>Title</label>
            <type>text</type>
        </title>
        <products_count translate="label">
            <visible>1</visible>
            <required>1</required>
            <label>No of Products</label>
            <type>text</type>
        </products_count>
        <ids translate="label">
            <visible>1</visible>
            <required>1</required>
            <label>Products</label>
            <type>label</type>
            <helper_block>
                <type>namespace_modulename/adminhtml_catalog_product_widget_multiproducts_chooser</type>
                <data>
                    <button translate="open">
                        <open>Select Products...</open>
                    </button>
                </data>
            </helper_block>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </ids>
        <template translate="label description">
            <required>1</required>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <label>Product Carousel Template</label>
            <type>text</type>
            <value>catalog/product/widget/products_carousel.phtml</value>
            <values>
                <default translate="label">                                                       <value>catalog/product/widget/products_carousel.phtml</value>
                    <label>New Products Grid Template</label>
                </default>
                <list translate="label">
                    <value>catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml</value>
                    <label>New Products List Template</label>
                </list>
            </values>
            <description>Template path cannot be changed/updated</description>
        </template>       
    </parameters>
  </catalog_product_multiproducts>
</widgets>
```

> /NameSpace/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/MultiProducts/Chooser.php

This function will call the DOCHOOSE() function which will help "Choose" the checked/selected products.

```
/**
 * prepare layout for products grid
 * 
 * @return type Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Widget_Chooser
 */
 protected function _prepareLayout()
 {
    $this->setChild('choose_button', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                    ->setData(array(
                        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Choose Selected Products'),
                        'onclick' => $this->getJsObjectName() . '.doChoose()'
                    ))
    );
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

The below function needs to be used to prepare the product element's HTML, in the format {1}{2}

```
/**
 * Prepare chooser element HTML
 *
 * @param Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element Form Element
 * @return Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract
 */
public function prepareElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $uniqueId = Mage::helper('core')->uniqHash($element->getId());

    $sourceUrl = $this->getUrl('*/multiproducts/chooser', array(
        'uniq_id' => $uniqueId,
        'use_massaction' => true,
    ));

    $chooser = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('widget/adminhtml_widget_chooser')
            ->setElement($element)
            ->setTranslationHelper($this->getTranslationHelper())
            ->setConfig($this->getConfig())
            ->setFieldsetId($this->getFieldsetId())
            ->setSourceUrl($sourceUrl)
            ->setUniqId($uniqueId);

    if ($element->getValue())
    {
        $label = "";
        $ids = explode('}{', $element->getValue());
        $cleanIds = array();
        foreach ($ids as $id)
        {
            $id = str_replace('{', '', $id);
            $id = str_replace('}', '', $id);
            $cleanIds[] = $id;
        }

        $products = $this->_getProductsByIDs($cleanIds);

        if ($products)
        {
            $label .= '<ul>';
            foreach ($products as $product)
            {
                $label .= '<li>' . $product->getName() . '</li>';
            }
            $label .= '</ul>';
            $chooser->setLabel($label);
        }
    }

    $element->setData('after_element_html', $chooser->toHtml());

    return $element;
}
```

JS for checkbox checked/unchecked

```
/**
 * Checkbox Check JS Callback
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCheckboxCheckCallback()
{
    if ($this->getUseMassaction())
    {
        return "function (grid, element) {
            $(grid.containerId).fire('product:changed', {element: element});                 
        }";
    }
}
```

JS for Row/Product Clicked/Checked/Selected

```
/**
 * Grid Row JS Callback
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRowClickCallback()
{
    if (!$this->getUseMassaction())
    {
        $chooserJsObject = $this->getId();
        return '
            function (grid, event) {
                var trElement = Event.findElement(event, "tr");
                var productId = trElement.down("td").innerHTML;
                var productName = trElement.down("td").next().next().innerHTML;
                var optionLabel = productName;
                var optionValue = "product/" + productId.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
                if (grid.categoryId) {
                    optionValue += "/" + grid.categoryId;
                }
                if (grid.categoryName) {
                    optionLabel = grid.categoryName + " / " + optionLabel;
                }
                ' . $chooserJsObject . '.setElementValue(optionValue);
                ' . $chooserJsObject . '.setElementLabel(optionLabel);
                ' . $chooserJsObject . '.close();
            }
        ';
    }
}
```

JS code, if user is interested in selecting products from specific category.

```
/**
 * Category Tree node onClick listener js function
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCategoryClickListenerJs()
{
    $js = '
        function (node, e) {
            {jsObject}.addVarToUrl("category_id", node.attributes.id);
            {jsObject}.reload({jsObject}.url);
            {jsObject}.categoryId = node.attributes.id != "none" ? node.attributes.id : false;
            {jsObject}.categoryName = node.attributes.id != "none" ? node.text : false;
        }
    ';

    $js = str_replace('{jsObject}', $this->getJsObjectName(), $js);

    return $js;
}
```

Additional JS for preparing the POST element with product ids.

```
/**
 * return additional JS for controls
 * 
 * @return JS
 */
public function getAdditionalJavascript()
{
    $chooserJsObject = $this->getId();

    $js = '    
        {jsObject}.initChecked = function() {
            $$("#' . $chooserJsObject . '_table tbody input:checkbox").each(function(element, i) {
                var values = ' . $chooserJsObject . '.getElementValue();
                var capture = values.replace("{"+element.value+"}", "match");                    
                var searchValue = "match";

                if(capture.search(searchValue) != -1)
                {
                    element.checked = true;
                }
            });
        }

        {jsObject}.initChecked();

        var values = ' . $chooserJsObject . '.getElementValue();

        $("' . $chooserJsObject . '").insert({bottom: "<div class=\"filter\"><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"+values+\" name=\"selected_products\" /></div>"});

        $$("#' . $chooserJsObject . '_table tbody input:checkbox").invoke("observe", "change", function(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);
            var label = element.up("td").next().next().next().innerHTML;
            label = label.replace(/^\s\s*/, "").replace(/\s\s*$/, "");
            if(element.checked)
            {
                {jsObject}.addValue(element.value);
                {jsObject}.addLabel(label);
            } else {
                {jsObject}.removeValue(element.value);
                {jsObject}.removeLabel(label);
            }
        });

        {jsObject}.removeValue = function(value) {
            var currentValue =  ' . $chooserJsObject . '.getElementValue();
            currentValue =  currentValue.replace("{"+value+"}", "");
            ' . $chooserJsObject . '.setElementValue(currentValue);
        }

        {jsObject}.addValue = function(value) {
            var currentValue = ' . $chooserJsObject . '.getElementValue();
            currentValue = currentValue.replace("{"+value+"}", "");
            currentValue = currentValue + "{"+value+"}";
            ' . $chooserJsObject . '.setElementValue(currentValue);
        }

        {jsObject}.removeLabel = function(label) {
            var currentLabel =  ' . $chooserJsObject . '.getElementLabelText();
            currentLabel = currentLabel.replace("<li>"+label+"</li>", "");
            ' . $chooserJsObject . '.setElementLabel(currentLabel);         
        }

        {jsObject}.addLabel = function(label) {
            var currentLabel = ' . $chooserJsObject . '.getElementLabelText();
            if(currentLabel.search("ul") != -1)
            {
                currentLabel = currentLabel.replace("</ul>", "");
                currentLabel = currentLabel.replace("<li>"+label+"</li>", "");
            } else {
                currentLabel = "<ul>";
            }    
            currentLabel = currentLabel +"<li>"+label+"</li></ul>";
            ' . $chooserJsObject . '.setElementLabel(currentLabel);
        }

        {jsObject}.doChoose = function(node,e) {
            ' . $chooserJsObject . '.close();
        }
    ';

    $js = str_replace('{jsObject}', $this->getJsObjectName(), $js);

    return $js;
}
```

The above are the major functions which will help you select multiple products from the GRID within a pop up.

There is a bit more to the code which can be checked here: https://github.com/dio5/magento-multiproducts-widget

Steps:

> 1. Navigate to a CMS Page in ADMIN panel
> 2. Click on "Insert Widget" in WYSIWYG editor
> 3. Select Widget Type - Catalog Multiple Products Widget
> 4. Enter Title, Products Count
> 5. Choose a template (One can add as many templates as required as an option)
> 6. Click on "Select Products" button
> 7. Select products from the GRID
> 8. Click on "Choose Selected Products" button

Hope this helps someone!

Happy Coding...

Comment: Please share the code in your answer instead of linking to them, at least the essential parts.

Comment: Have tried to edit my answer and provide major code blocks. This might be helpful for someone going forward. Thanks!

Comment: This code is working properly. But it have one issue like in widget left side we can't make filter product with category.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you're not the first to go down the path of developing your own implementation for this.

[David Manners](https://github.com/dmanners) appears to have tackled the same issue, with his [Manners_Widgets](https://github.com/dmanners/Manners_Widgets).

> Features of the Manners_Widgets Extension:
>
> - **Multiple select for products and categories**

I've not had contact with David, nor have I used this solution, so can't comment on quality (or completeness) of this code... but if you haven't already seen this solution, it might save you some time (or at worst, give you a point of contact for collaboration on this issue).

Hope this helps you, good luck with it!

Comment: yes I started looking into this issue but sadly have not had much time or luck lately :( it is on gitHub if anyone fancies taking a look and helping out feel free. I will update here if I find a solution

Comment: I just tried the extension on Magento 1.9x. the select mask comes from the product list and has buttons like "change status" and "Change Attributes" but no actual "select" button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix: don't use the product widget chooser, but use a textfield instead that allows for comma separated SKUs.

Then in your code explode the skus and get the products by sku. Return that to your template. Much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to https://github.com/dio5/magento-multiproducts-widget.

It seems very useful.